# Why do I receive an error when I try to use the JOSM remote in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, josm, quickosm

I've installed the QuickOSM plugin on QGIS. I also have a functional installation of JOSM on my computer (Ubuntu 20.04). However, when I try to run JOSM on QGIS I get the error `JOSM Remote: Is the remote enabled in the JOSM settings?`.

[image]

On the JOSM settings, I have enabled remote control. But it doesn't solve this problem:

[image]

What am I getting wrong? Is there any extra procedure I have to do in order to use JOSM inside QGIS with the QuickOSM plugin?

Comment: Is JOSM running at the time of the error? Also, shouldn't you update it?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Ah yeah, it works perfectly fine when JOSM is opened. I was expecting QGIS to use its command line to download the data and show it on the map. But what actually happens is that it shows the data on JOSM. About the update, I should probably update it. I didn't think it'd be a problem because JOSM works fine alone. Well, just opening JOSM solved this problem, thanks!

Comment: It doesn't open JOSM, it just send a request to zoom in the specific region and download data so JOSM must be running to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use JOSM Remote, **JOSM has to be open**.

It doesn't open JOSM, it just send a request to zoom in the region corresponding to QGIS canvas and download openstreetmap data.